# <aside> tag usage confusion

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I read about `<aside>` tag here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_aside.asp, but unable to understand the real motive of this tag.

What is the difference between a content in this tag and the one outside?

I mean if content is related but different than content surrounding this tag, then `div` can be used. What is special about this tag in comparison to other old container tags? Is it helpful in SEO?

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML5, everything in `body` is part of a *section*. Every section can have a `header` and a `footer`. Everything *not* in `header`/`footer` can be considered the main content of that section. The [`aside` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/sections.html#the-aside-element) can be used for "content that is considered separate from the main content of the page".

If you’d use `div` instead of `aside`, its content couldn’t be separated from the other, "real" main content of that `article`:

```
<article>
  <h1>Cute cat</h1>
  <p>I like cats.</p>
  <div class="aside">
    <!-- and now for something completely different -->
  </div>
  <p>Next time, I get a dog.</p>
</article>
```

If you wouldn’t use HTML5’s sectioning elements for that content, the only alternative would be to use explicit headings (this is what we would have to do in HTML 4.01):

```
<article>
  <h1>Cute cat</h1>
  <p>I like cats.</p>
  <div class="aside">
    <h2>Good cat litter boxes</h2>
    <!-- and now for something completely different -->
  </div>
  <p>Next time, I get a dog.</p>
</article>
```

Problem: the last `p` would be in scope of the `h2` (which starts a new implicit section). But this `p` isn’t about the cat litter box advertisement, it’s part of the content from before the `div`.

Solution:

```
<article>
  <h1>Cute cat</h1>
  <p>I like cats.</p>
  <aside>
    <h2>Good cat litter boxes</h2>
    <!-- and now for something completely different -->
  </aside>
  <p>Next time, I get a dog.</p>
</article>
```

Now it’s clear which is the main content of that `article`:

> **Cute cat**
>   I like cats.
>   Next time, I get a dog.

And the `aside` is tangentially related to the parent section: both are about cats, and you only posted this cat litter box advertisement because you a writing about cats in that `article`.

User agents could do all kind of stuff with this information. Search engines could lower the relevance of that content (if or which services do that is a different question and probably off-topic on SO), browsers could display these as sidebars, extractors could ignore them, screen readers could skip them when reading the main content, etc.

Comment: Thanks. That explains alot. My conclusion from your answer is that the `<aside>` tag just represents something related but less important. Now, its on browsers and crawlers how they handle this unimportant but related info. And I think none of them taken care of that till now.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva: I wouldn’t say "less important". The content of the `aside` *could* be very important. It’s just that it is separate from the content around it. It isn’t part of the main flow of the document. -- Yes, you might be right that most user agents don’t treat the markup in any way, but that’s hard to say as there are *so* many of them (and many, like search engines, don’t document what exactly they do).