# Semantic markup of multiple articles inside article with preambles/postscript

Tags: html, semantic-markup, article

As part of a project mentioned in connection with [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193850/how-to-handle-headers-in-html5) I need to markup nested articles in semantic HTML5. There's a magazine article containing a number of short texts by different authors plus some editor comments. In the present HTML4 version it looks something like this:

```
<div id="article">
    <h1>Main heading - a collection of texts</h1>

    <p id="intro">
        A general introduction to the whole collection by the editor.
    </p>

    <p class="preamble">
        A few words from the editor about the first text.
    </p>

    <h2>First text heading</h2>

    <p>First text. Lorem ipsum ...</p>

    <p class="author">
        Name of author of first text.
    </p>

    <div>*</div>

    <p class="preamble">
        A few words from the editor about the second text.
    </p>

    <h2>Second text heading</h2>

    <p>Second text. Dolorem ipsum ...</p>

    <p class="author">
        Name of author of second text.
    </p>

    <p id="postscript">
        Some final words about the whole collection by the editor.
    </p>
<div>
```

I have been considering something like this in HTML5, but there are some elements where I simply don't know what's best:

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h1>Main heading</h1>
        <ELEMENT>
            General introduction
        </ELEMENT>
    </header>

    <article>
        <header>
            <ELEMENT>
                Preamble
            </ELEMENT>
            <h2>
                Article heading
            </h2>
        </header>
        <p>
            Article text
        </p>
        <ELEMENT>
            Name of author
        </ELEMENT>
    </article>

    <div>*</div>

    <article>
        Second article ...
    </article>

    <ELEMENT>
        Postscript by editor
    </ELEMENT>
</article>
```

Should I use a `p` element with class names for the various introductions and postscript, or maybe `aside` elements? Something else? And the same question regarding the names of authors. The `address` element doesn't seem quite right there. A `footer` perhaps with some other element (?) in it?

Edit: Occasionally there are some images as well and the photographer is mentioned in small print at the end of the article ("Photo: John Doe."). Element x inside a `footer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first question should be *where* to put the editor comment for an article. I can think of three ways:

- **(a)** editor comment in the `header` of an `article`

  ```
  <article class="author-text">
    <header class="editor-comment"></header>
  </article>
  ```
- **(b)** editor comment in an `article` that is nested in an `article`

  ```
  <article class="author-text">
    <article class="editor-comment"></article>
  </article>
  ```
- **(c)** editor comment in a `section` that has the `article` as child

  ```
  <section class="editor-comment">
    <article class="author-text"></article>
  </section>
  ```

You are using **(a)** in your question. I don’t think it’s the best choice, mainly because this `article` would contain content from different authors (that did not work together), so the concept of "nearest `article` element ancestor" for denoting authorship wouldn’t work. It’s used, for example, by the [`author` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#link-type-author) and the [`address` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-address-element).

**(b)** and **(c)** don’t have this problem. In **(b)**, each editor could have their own authorship info, in **(c)** the authorship info for the editor would be taken from the parent `article` (which includes the whole collection of articles), so the editor would have to be same everytime.

The [definition of `article`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-article-element) suggests that **(b)** is appropriate:

> When `article` elements are nested, the inner `article` elements represent articles that are in principle related to the contents of the outer article.

It would make sense to include this editor comment `article` in a `header`.

The authorship information could be placed in a `footer`. [Only if](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26188004/1591669) this information contains contact information for the author, use an `address` element in addition (and only for these contact information parts).

So a single short text could look like this:

```
<article class="author-text">
  <h1>First text heading</h1>
  <header>
    <article>
      <p>Editor comment</p>
    </article>
  </header>
  <p>First paragraph of the text …</p>
  <footer>
    <!-- text author information -->
    <!-- use 'address' here if appropriate -->
  </footer>
</article>
```

The whole collection could be structured like this:

```
<article class="text-collection">

  <h1>Main heading</h1>

  <p>General introduction</p>

  <article class="author-text"></article>
  <article class="author-text"></article>
  <article class="author-text"></article>
  <article class="author-text"></article>

  <p>Postscript by editor</p>

</article>
```

Comment: Thanks again for an informative reply. Yes, I agree that `h1` (not `h2`) is what I should use for each subarticle heading ("First text heading" in your example), but I don't understand why you put it before the header instead of inside it. Would that be inappropriate in this case?

Comment: @linurb: You don’t have to use `h1` (in fact, HTML5 [recommends](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24987792/1591669) to use "headings of the appropriate rank for the section's nesting level"). -- Regarding `header`: Yes, it’s appropriate and common to include the heading in `header`.